# Problem with creating user based relationships in graphql

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, strapi

When attempting to create a mutation to create something that has any type of relation to my user class, it doesn't work. I've tried passing in the user ID, the whole user object, and the "data" part of the response only. Does anyone have an answer to this? (Most likely it's a problem with my Apollo schema. I'm extremely new to graphql + apollo, literally day 3.)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

const ADD_SHIUR = gql`
  mutation createShiurimMutation($input: createShiurimInput!) {
    createShiurim(data: $input) {
      shiurim {
        title
        description
        link
        user {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default function AddShiur({ user }) {
  const [addShiur] = useMutation(ADD_SHIUR);
  const [title, CTS] = useState("");
  const [description, CDS] = useState("");
  const [link, CLS] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
        id="title"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Title"
        onChange={(e) => CTS(e.target.value)}
      />
      <textarea
        className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
        id="description"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Description"
        onChange={(e) => CDS(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
        id="link"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Shiur link"
        onChange={(e) => CLS(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          addShiur({
            variables: {
              title: title,
              description: description,
              link: link,
              user: { id: user.id },
            },
          });
        }}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `input` is your required object variable

Comment: I had i feeling it had something to do with that... should all the data be grouped and passed as one object to $input in the method?